# adding exogeneous variables to auto arima in pyramid package

Tags: python, arima, pyramid-arima

I'm a big fan of auto.arima in r, like the example below.  I was excited to hear there's a python version in the pyramid package, (example below.)

Does anyone know if you can add predictors or exogeneous variables in the pyramid version when training a model?  In the r version you add them in the xreg argument.

r code:

```
auto.arima(df, xreg=pred_df)
```

python code:

```
from pyramid.arima import auto_arima

auto_arima(df)
```

Update:

I found the answer:

```
auto_arima(df, exogeneous=pred_df)
```

does anybody know if pyramid works on python 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyramid does work with Python 2.7. I'm running a model now.